# Change Preprocessor value in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

Is there any way to change a preprocessor value like:

```
#define XValue 50
```

in Objective-C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean changing it during runtime, then no, as `XValue` is replaced with `50` before compilation.

If you mean changing it in the compilation, then yes, using `#undef` and `#define`.

Example:

```
XValue = 30; // NOT ALLOWED

#undef XValue // ALLOWED
#define XValue 30
```

Comment: i mean during runtime .. anyway thanks so much and i will make your answer acceptable

Answer (score 2):

```
#undef XValue
#define XValue 100
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
int global_mutable_value = 50; 
#define XValue global_mutable_value
```

Or just

```
int XValue = 50;
```

You don't say why you want `XValue` to be a macro, so we can't tell whether your intentions for it would be satisfied by something that can change at runtime. If they would, use something that can change at runtime instead of a macro (I've used an extern variable). If they wouldn't, then of course you're out of luck.