# Change #define values for iPhone Vs iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to make a universal app for iPhone. I have a few #define values in my *.m file

```
#define VERTICAL_GAP_SIZE 120
#define FIRST_OBSTACLE_PADDING 100
#define OBSTACLE_MIN_HEIGHT 60
#define OBSTACLE_INTERVAL_SPACE 130
```

down in the code it is being used like this (and whole lot other places)

```
...
float maxVariance = availableSpace - (2*OBSTACLE_MIN_HEIGHT) - VERTICAL_GAP_SIZE;
```

Now these values are all good if I am running my app on a iphone. For iPad I want to change these values, I just don't know how? I mean if I try this its a compiler error.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        //its iphone
    }
    else
    {
        //its ipad
      VERTICAL_GAP_SIZE = 120
    }
```

I don't want to create new #define just for iPad as these values are being used in a lot of places in my code.

Comment: to future people, like rckoenes said it cannot be done. I had to change #define to static int and then do iPhone vs ipad check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949052/change-preprocessor-value-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can't really, since a `#define` is precompile marco and is not available at run time when you are checking for the `userInterfaceIdiom`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should change these defines to static int, right?